Integers in decimal base to binary base conversion: Is this non-iterative method valid?
Integers in decimal base to binary base conversion: Is this non-iterative method valid?
Working in an unrelated experiment in Excel, I was trying to make an optimization problem where I require to evaluate all possible combinations among $20$ elements $x_j,\  j=\{1,\ 2,\cdots,\ 20\}$, which are $2^{20} = 1,048,576$ different combinations (the whole rows of $1$ Excel spreadsheet since I don't care about the $\vec{0}$ element), and for making a "selection" vector $$\vec{a}:= a_j \begin{cases} 1,\ x_j\text{ to be considered},\\ 0,\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ to choose among the $x_j$ elements as a dot product $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x}$, I thought to make a decimal index $d_i,\ i=\{1,\ 2,\cdots,\ 2^{20}-1\}$ and make $\vec{a}$ a row which every element is the $2^{j}$-element of the binary description of $d_i$, this to be sure I were not missing any combination - if interested, the optimization problem is in this other question, but is not relevant now.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    & 2^{0} & 2^{1} & 2^{2} & 2^{3} & 2^{4} & \cdots & 2^{18} & 2^{19} \\
d_i & a_1   & a_2   & a_3   & a_4   & a_5   & \cdots & a_{19} & a_{20} \\ \hline
1   & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\ \hline
2   & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\ \hline
3   & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
1,048,575 & 1 & 1   & 1     & 1     & 1     & \cdots & 1      & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
But looking for methods to convert decimal to binary in YouTube, I found only two: doing iterative subtractions, or iterative division by $2$ and keeping the remainders, both too cumbersome for my ambitions - a few examples: video 1, video 2, MSE question 1, MSE question 2, MSE question 3.
Later, by trial and error looking for something more easy I found the following:
$$a_j(d_i):= 0+1\cdot \text{ISODD}\left(\text{QUOTIENT}\left(d_i;\ 2^{j-1}\right)\right)$$

I tested it by going backwards: $d_i -\left(a_{1}2^{0}+a_{2}2^1+a_{3}2^{2}\cdots a_{20}2^{19}\right)$ and it give me zero for all $i=\{1,\ 2,\cdots,\ 2^{20}-1\}$ so it looks it works fine. I was not requiring it, but you can easily obtain the the binary digit $b_i$ by concatenation in Excel $b_i := a_{20}\&a_{19}\&\cdots\&a_{3}\&a_{2}\&a_{1}$.
Since I have no mathematical explanation of why it works, neither of if will fail after some number (honestly I just thought that every digit only have two alternatives so some easier way must exist and tried some stuff until I found this), I am looking to some reference source to this method or some explanation of why it works, and maybe it also could be useful for some other users here (it was for me, just one formula for sweep and fill all cells).

@peterwhy I think “1,048,576” in the table is a typo for “1,048,575,” which is $2^{20}-1$ (the $2^{20}$-th smallest integer starting from zero. $a_1$ is the rightmost binary digit, which as you note should be $1$ for every odd integer.

@peterwhy thanks I missed with the index when starting from $1$ instead than from $0$, the other was explained by Steve Kass

Your Excel formula is also mentioned in MSE question 1 in another format: the $2^i$s bit of $A$ or $a_{i+1}(A)$ is "$(A / 2^i) % 2$" (using their notation with integer division $/$) or $\left\lfloor \dfrac A{2^i}\right\rfloor \bmod 2$.

Your formula is fine, it does exactly what you need it to do, and really it's doing the iterative "divide and modulo" in the background.
The QUOTIENT function calculates integer division - i.e. it divides one input by the other and gives the result truncated as an integer. So if you have a number with a binary representation $A = \overline{a_n a_{n-1} \ldots a_1 a_0}_2$, i.e. $A = 2^n a_n + \ldots + 2^1 a_1 + 2^0 a_0$ and you take QUOTIENT(A, 2^j) you're going to chop off the last $j$ terms, giving you $2^{n-j} a_n + \ldots + 2^1 a_{j+1} + 2^0 a_j$. Then ISODD will essentially just tell you whether $a_j$ is 1 or 0, because every other term in the quotient is being multiplied by a power of 2 and will hence not contribute to the value being odd or even.
If you wanted to shrink the formula down, then you could write it as something like =MOD(BITRSHIFT(A2, COLUMN() - 2), 2). It does the same thing, but the BITRSHIFT function works directly on the binary values without going through explicit division, and MOD returns an integer so you don't have to mess around with the 0 + 1 * shenanigans.

Thanks for the answer, it explains really well what is happening. As a comment: the shenanigan you mentioned is quite useful for avoiding problems in Excel (I give you my word as an ex-business analyst lol)
